# Why doesn't kicking people work using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"),
    bot = new Discord.Client();
let pre = "?";
bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
    var msgArray = msg.content.split(" ");
    var args = msgArray.slice(1);
    var prisonerRole = msg.guild.roles.find("name", "Prisoner");
    let command = msgArray[0];
    if (command == `${pre}roll`) {
        if (!msg.member.roles.has(prisonerRole.id)) {
            roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            msg.reply(`You rolled a ${roll}`);
        } else {
            msg.reply(`HaHa NOOB, you're in prison you don't get priveleges!`);
        }
    }
    if (command == `${pre}kick`) {
        var leaderRole = msg.guild.roles.find("name", "LEADER");
        var co_leaderRole = msg.guild.roles.find("name", "CO-LEADER");
        if (
            msg.member.roles.has(leaderRole.id) ||
            msg.member.roles.has(co_leaderRole.id)
        ) {
            var kickUser = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first());
            var kickReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
            msg.guild.member(kickUser).kick();
            msg.channel.send(
                `${msg.author} has kicked ${kickUser}\nReason: ${kickReason}`
            );
        } else {
            return msg.reply("Ya pleb, you can't kick people!");
        }
    }
});
bot.login("token").then(
    function () {
        console.log("Good!");
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("Still good, as long as the process now exits.");
        bot.destroy();
    }
);
```

Everything works except actually kicking the person. The message sends nut it doesn't kick people. For example, when I type in `?kick @BobNuggets#4576 inactive`, it says 
`@rishabhase has kicked @BobNuggets Reason: inactive`
But it doesn't actually kick the user, which is weird, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
msg.guild.member(kickUser).kick();
```

to

```
kickUser.kick();
```

also, make sure the bot is elevated in hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Use `kickUser.kick();`

I recommend using a command handler to neaten up your code. You don't want all your commands in one .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for the Ban command itself. I use this for my Bot:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
if (message.content.startsWith("!ban")) {
    if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Role that can use this bot"))
        return;
    // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
    var member = message.mentions.members.first();
    // ban
    member
        .ban()
        .then((member) => {
            // Successmessage
            message.channel.send(
                ":wave: " +
                    member.displayName +
                    " has been successfully banned :point_right: "
            );
        })
        .catch(() => {
            // Failmessage
            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
}
});
```

That should work, set the role you want to use it (cAsE sEnSiTiVe) and change !ban to whatever you feel like using. If you change all "ban"s in this to kick, it will have the same effect.